# How to wait for addListenerForSingleValueEvent to work

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to write a class for the `FirebaseDatabase` that makes my activities code shorter.

I have in my Database node "events" and I want to make a method that returns all the events in the node.

```
public HashMap getEvents() {
    mDatabase.child("events").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            getValue = dataSnapshot.getValue();
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
    return (HashMap)getValue;
}
```

The problem is that it doesn't wait for the Listener to do its job and it goes straight to the return while `getValue` is still null.
How can I fix that so it returns the value only when the listener activates?

Comment: By the time `return (HashMap)getValue` your `getValue = dataSnapshot.getValue();` hasn't been called yet. Any code that needs to have access to the data from Firebase, needs to be inside `onDataChange` or be called from there. See my answer here for a longer explanation and example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50434836/getcontactsfromfirebase-method-return-an-empty-list/50435519#50435519

Comment: Yes I know that this is the reason, I am searching for how to return the value when the listener will activate. And I will see thanks!